# How to change the positioning of two different texts in opposite directions in geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot the estimates "0.548" and "0.604" using the following code:

```
df %>%
  mutate(label = replace(round(est, 3), x != -6 & x != 12, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,est, label = label)) +
  geom_text(hjust = 1.2, size=5) +
  geom_line(, size= 1.5) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-8, 14))+ 
  theme_classic()+
  theme()
```

But my aim is to move the 0.604 position to the right side of the line while keeping the 0.548 to its left. Is there any way to do it?

[image]

Here is the data:

```
   structure(list(x = c(-6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Working class", class = "factor"), 
    est = c(0.547944792197329, 0.55727970599782, 0.566614619798308, 
    0.575949533598797, 0.585284447399287, 0.594619361199776, 
    0.603954275000266)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), groups = structure(list(
    x = c(-6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12), .rows = structure(list(1L, 
        2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's bound to be a more elegant way of doing this, here is one option.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

    ggplot(df, aes(x, est)) +
    geom_text(data = filter(df, est == max(df$est)), aes(x, est, label = round(est, 3)), hjust = -0.2, size=5) +
    geom_text(data = filter(df, est == min(df$est)),  aes(x, est, label = round(est, 3)), hjust = 1.2, size=5) +
    geom_line(, size= 1.5) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-8, 14))+ 
    theme_classic()+
    theme()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>